# Using an Alternative PDF reader with R Studio

Tags: pdf, rstudio

What is the proper way to configure R Studio to use an alternative PDF reader ?

I have tried this:

```
Sys.setenv(R_PDFVIEWER = "/Applications/Skim")
```

But this seems to not work ... I have also tried placing this application in the R Studio working home directory found by:

```
> Sys.getenv('HOME')
[1] "/Users/toohru"
And still only the default view pops up.
```

Thanks for the support in advance !

-toohru

See above statement in the problem statement